# How can I move my cart from my header into the right of my navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, rwd-theme, menu, toplinks

I would like to know how to **move my cart icon into my navigation instead of the header**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to remove the original cart link from the top links.

Edit (or create) `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/local.xml` and add the following code under the `<default>` layout handle:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>

     <!-- To re-add 'Checkout' after removing both -->
     <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_link_custom">
         <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
     </block>
</reference>

<reference name="catalog.topnav">
     <block type="page/template_links" name="catalog.links">
         <block type="checkout/links" name="cart_link_custom">
             <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
         </block>
     </block>
</reference>
```

The problem at this point is that the template that renders the menu does not automatically display the child blocks so you will have to create (or edit) `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml` with the following code:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>

<?php if($_menu): ?>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ol class="nav-primary">
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ol>
    </nav>
<?php endif ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.links'); ?>
```

If you want to add the cart link before the menu then move `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.links'); ?>` at the top of the template.